# git pull says config/environments/development.rb is not committed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Doing a pull from master into my local branch on a shared ROR project. Git says:

> branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD error: Your local changes
>   to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>     config/environments/development.rb Please, commit your changes or
>   stash them before you can merge. Aborting

`development.rb` is not showing up as having been modified, and, in fact, when I actually do modify it, it still doesn't show as having been modified. This is happening on all branches, effectively preventing me from merging in master.

I should say here that I am a designer on this project and my ROR and Git skills are not huge (I have mostly been using the Tower GUI for managing branches). However, I've been successfully contributing to the project for over a year and never came across this issue before.

Comment: Well I fixed it by removing development.rb from my local repo and then pulling from master which added the most recent from the remote repo. And now development.rb is showing up as having been modified if I edit it. So I don't know what caused it, but I seem to have fixed it.  
  
As I commented below, just before this started happening, I had started pulling from a wrong branch and cancelled the pull before it was done. I'm guessing this somehow put development.rb into a state where it couldn't be seen by Git.

Answer (score 0):

If you type 'git status' do you see development.rb in the list of untracked files?  If so you need to 'git add' it and commit.

Alternately, in the root of your project look at .gitignore and see if it's listed in there for some weird reason.  It shouldn't be, but it's worth looking.

Comment: I actually tried both those things before posting. Git status reports nothing to commit. And .gitignore doesn't contain "development.rb"

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling that you are using `git update-index --assume-unchanged development.rb`, but don't remember it. If it is the case, use `--no-assume-unchanged` then.

Comment: I mostly use Tower and not the command line and I certainly never issued any commands like those.

Comment: Another possible cause: just before this started happening, I accidentally started pulling from the wrong branch and immediately cancelled the pull. Again this was using Tower. I then checked out a previous backup copy of the branch I had fortunately made before the aborted pull. And that's when the issue started. So maybe the aborted pull somehow messed up my environment?

Comment: @user2646308 I suspect there is a similar option in Tower. Try to look around.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without looking at your .gitignore but you could have config/environments/development.rb in that file, in which case you wouldn't see changes.

But that isn't the real issue, it sounds like you just need to commit then pull. This is what I would do.

Add config/environments/development.rb to your commit, commit changes then pull. If that doesn't work, I would just delete your local copy and clone a new one.

I hope that helps.

Comment: As I said, Git status reports nothing to commit. And .gitignore doesn't contain "development.rb"

However, getting a recent copy of the file is something I could try.